# Trouble with xattr, "No module named 'pkg_resources' "

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, pkg-resources, xattr

I've been on MacOS using Python for a while and lately, when trying to execute MacOS's xattr, such as `xattr -cr <file>` I'm always getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr", line 8, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I've done a lot of research and tried reinstalling setuptools and pip, but I'm still getting the same error. I'd appreciate if anyone could lead me to a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Doing a clean OS reinstall was the solution.